# TFS Code reviews - Can you run someones changeset locally to test that it works?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2017, tfvc

I'm used to using Git branches to develop features for products before merging them onto a main develop branch. Normally I would check out another developer's branch as soon as they have a pull request up, so that I can test their changes alongside reviewing their actual code.

I've recently joined a team that is using TFS with Team Foundation Version Control (so not Git). I'm comfortable enough with issuing and reviewing code reviews, but is there a way to run someone else's shelveset*? Preferably without overwriting my own files if we're both working on the same ones?

In a person's code review I'm able to see Actions, and ViewChangeset to view the checked-in changeset. This has more Actions to select from. But none of them appear to allow the running of their changes in my local workspace.

*UPDATE:
Please see Daniel Mann's answer on correct terminology I needed, namely: "A changeset is assigned to source code that has been committed and will be synchronized via "Get Latest" or the like. A shelveset is suspended, in-progress work."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's able to run someones' changeset locally to test, you just need to first [find their changeset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/find-view-changesets?view=vsts#search-for-changesets) by user and then pull down the specific changeset locally(suggest you create a new workspace to handle those files).

Changeset in TFVC is corresponding to commit in Git. There are already in TFS server source control.

However, code review occur **before others check in their code**.  Suggest you first [go through the process of code review](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/get-code-reviewed-vs?view=vsts) in TFVC. Just like *Daniel* said, code review based on [shelvesets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/suspend-your-work-manage-your-shelvesets?view=vsts).

Other peoples are sharing their **pending changes**(haven't checked in) to you for your review through shelveset. You could [unshelve his shelveset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/unshelve-command?view=vsts) which restores shelved file revisions, check-in notes, comments, and work item associations to the current workspace.

If you don't want the shelveset mess up your local work in VS, please also take a look at my reply here: [Undo TFS Unshelve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39270366/undo-tfs-unshelve/39283656#39283656)

Comment: Hi Patrick. I've used shelvesets a bit for saving my own in-progress work now. The code-review thing is a bit more complicated as I'm the only developer in my team, bar a contractor who comes in twice a week. So I tend to submit review requests on the days they're in or when I have a particularly complicated, upcoming changeset I'll need eyes on. Having said that, I believe your answer to be right as I have seen the checking out shelveset suggestion on a few more SO questions (albeit, without being from a Git perspective). So I will mark it correct. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Please note that you're using some terminology incorrectly which may lead to confusion now or in the future. A *changeset* is assigned to source code that has been committed and will be synchronized via "Get Latest" or the like. A *shelveset* is suspended, in-progress work.

TFVC code review operates off of **shelvesets**, not changesets.

With that clarified:
You have to shelve or check-in your changes, then unshelve their changes.

Comment: Great answer Daniel, and will update my question with your correct terminology. I think PatrickLu-MSFT is a little closer to what I need on this one so I'm going to give him the green tick.