# Compartilhar Shelve com outros Membros TFS

Tags: tfs

good morning, people!

A co-worker has made some changes to the project and now it is necessary to do the same so that I do my part now. However, he can not give a check-in because another team member "pulls" the latest version, it will pick up that part that no case could not, only I could remove those changes and after I do as the changes, yes do the standard check in.

This refeel a my doubt, should be something simple. And neither is it done the same for this not TFS. It's possible?

Comment: Please post in English, or use the appropriate localized version of Stack Overflow, such as https://pt.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Hello, good morning, people!

A co-worker has made some changes to the project and now it is necessary to do the same so that I do my part now. However, he can not give a check-in because another team member "pulls" the latest version, it will pick up that part that no case could not, only I could remove those changes and after I do as the changes, yes do the standard check in.

This refeel a my doubt, should be something simple. And neither is it done the same for this not TFS. It's possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your title is talking about how to share shelve with other TFS Members. There is a concert called **Shelvesets** in TFS. Shelvesets are useful when you want to stop work for:

> Collaboration: You have pending changes that are not ready for check
>   in but you need to share them with another team member.

Other peoples could share their **pending changes**(haven't checked in) to you through shelveset. You could [unshelve his shelveset](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/unshelve-command?view=vsts) which restores shelved file revisions, check-in notes, comments, and work item associations to the current workspace.

If you don't want the shelveset mess up your local work in VS, please also take a look at my reply here: [Undo TFS Unshelve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39270366/undo-tfs-unshelve/39283656#39283656)

Comment: Do you need some tutorial to run this kind of service, what would Shelvesets Collaboration be?

Comment: @AndrewMarques Yes there is a tutorial, you could simply follow the process in this link: [Suspend your work and manage your shelvesets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/suspend-your-work-manage-your-shelvesets?view=vsts) It shows how to  1.Suspend and resume your work from the My Work page 2.Shelve your changes 3.Find a shelveset  Then you could unshelve others' shelveset and keep on working it. Finally check in pending changes to TFS server.